# Fold over a function with || operator

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, visual-c++, c++17

Im trying to apply a function to each type in a parameterpack and then fold over the result.

Example:
https://godbolt.org/z/0YNon_

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
bool CheckCondition(std::uint64_t i){
    return i>sizeof(T);
}

template <typename... ToCheck>
bool AnyCheckCondition(std::uint64_t i){
    return CheckCondition<ToCheck>(i)||...;
}

int main() 
{
    return AnyCheckCondition<std::string,std::uint64_t, std::int64_t>(10);
}
```

Unfortunately the fold expression doesn't compile and I'm unsure why or how to fix it.

I get the following errors

```
<source>: In function 'bool AnyCheckCondition(uint64_t)':

<source>:11:35: error: parameter packs not expanded with '...':

     return CheckCondition<ToCheck>(i) || ...;

            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~

<source>:11:35: note:         'ToCheck'

<source>:11:38: error: expected ';' before '||' token

     return CheckCondition<ToCheck>(i) || ...;

                                      ^~~

                                      ;

<source>:11:39: error: expected primary-expression before '||' token

     return CheckCondition<ToCheck>(i) || ...;

                                       ^~

Compiler returned: 1
```

Comment: Please elaborate on `isn't particularly appreciated `

Comment: Doesn't compile

Comment: `return (CheckCondition<ToCheck>(i) || ...);` - you forgot parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fold expression has the form

```
( pack op ... )
( ... op pack )
( pack op ... op init )
( init op ... op pack )
```

You are missing those outer parentheses.  Changing the code to

```
return (CheckCondition<ToCheck>(i) || ...);
```

will get it to compile.

Comment: VTC as Simple Typo

Answer (score 4):

Fold expressions require the surrounding parentheses.

```
return (CheckCondition<ToCheck>(i) || ...);
```

Comment: VTC as Simple Typo